# Spark Socket Timeout issue while writing to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, timeout, hdfs

I am trying to process a hive query and write to HDFS as ORC format. But I am getting a timeout issue. I checked in spark-default.conf ,but there is no timeout settings, should i add it? Please let me know the changes to make

```
temp = sqlContext.sql(""" query """)
temp.write.format("orc").option("header", "true").save("hdfs://app/Quality/spark_test/")
```

Attached is the log of the error

```
: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From .. to app:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=app/64.100.51.136:8020]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=app/64.100.51.136:8020]
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:534)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1448)
        ... 41 more

Comment: Looks like you are having issues with the connection it self. Have you successfully written anything? Try a small file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from badly provided hdfs location. When you are providing `hdfs://app/` spark will assume that the namenode host name is `app`

So to solve this problem: in your code when you are providing the hdfs location you should:

1. Either  provide the namenode's hostname/or IP, so your code should be:

   ```
   temp.write.format("orc").option("header", "true").save("hdfs://NAMENODE_HOST:8020/app/Quality/spark_test/")
   ```
2. Or, if you have already configured Spark with HDFS/Yarn, by setting the configuration files' locations in spark-env.sh, providing the location on HDFS without the protocol (hdfs), so the code will be :

   ```
   temp.write.format("orc").option("header", "true").save("/app/Quality/spark_test/")
   ```