# TImeout error when writing with .saveAsTable to HDFS after data is written

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm running Spark 2.3 on EMR and trying to write data to HDFS using Scala as follows:

```
dataframe.write.
  partitionBy("column1").
  bucketBy(1,"column2").
  sortBy("column2").
  mode("overwrite").
  format("parquet").
  option("path","hdfs:///destination/").
  saveAsTable("result")
```

Once the data is written and the tasks finishes I get a timeout error. After the error I can see the data in HDFS, fully processed.

Why does this error occur? Does it mean anything?

It looks like the master node is trying to communicate to another IP (which doesn't match any of the node IPs), but the data is already in HDFS.

Note that this does not happen when using `.save("hdfs:///location/")` or `.save("s3://bucket/folder/")`, only with the `saveAsTable` method. I need to use `saveAsTable` in order to bucket and sort.

Error log snippets below

```
18/07/23 16:33:31 WARN HiveExternalCatalog: Persisting bucketed data source table `default`.`result` into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format, which is NOT compatible with Hive.
18/07/23 16:35:32 ERROR log: Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException Call From ip-master_node_ip/master.node.ip to other_ip.ec2.internal:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=other_ip.ec2.internal/other_ip:8020]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From ip-master_node_ip/master.node.ip to other_ip.ec2.internal:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=other_ip.ec2.internal/other_ip:8020]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout

at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=other_ip.ec2.internal/other_ip:8020]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3500(Client.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1381)
    ... 110 more
    18/07/23 16:35:32 ERROR log: Converting exception to MetaException
    org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From ip-master_node_ip/master.node.ip to other_ip.ec2.internal:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=other_ip.ec2.internal/other_ip:8020]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout

  ... 49 elided
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=other_ip.ec2.internal/other_ip:8020]
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:534)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:685)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:788)
```

For reference, I tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369676/spark-socket-timeout-issue-while-writing-to-hdfs), but the error still comes up when specifying the master node IP in the path `hdfs:///master_node_ip:8020/location/")`.

Comment: I normally use the insertInto method. I never tried with bucketBy though, i dont have the environment handy now, try with the below and let me know i will put it in my environment and test if it dosen't work for you.datagrame.write.partitionBy("column1").bucketBy(1,"column2").sortBy("column2").mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("path","hdfs:///destination/").insertInto("result")

Comment: this is the error with .insertInto

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'insertInto' does not support bucketing right now`

Comment: When you `saveAsTable` you are saving the files _and_ also creating a Hive table for it. You can see it in the first line of the logs. The error is most likely related to the impossibility of writing to the Hive metastore, you may want to look into that.

Comment: Interesting. I guess given that the `save` operation does not allow for bucketing, i'll just live with the error for now, knowing that it doesn't really affect what needs to be done. Thanks!

Comment: final resolution. the issue is with saving to the default database. when using saveAsTable without specifying the database, it assumed ```default.```. i went ahead and created a database ```spark.sql("create database tmp```") and then saved to it ```saveAsTable("tmp.mytable")```. the error is gone and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your EMR cluster is using the Glue MetaStore by default, and that Database doesn't exist there, then you'll see that timeout. You can either remove the configuration or create the database as suggested

```
Classification: hive-site
Property: hive.metastore.client.factory.class
Value: com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory
Source: Cluster configuration
```